# Using Djangos ImageField to upload an image, rename it to a random filename and create thumbnail

Tags: python, django, file, upload

Hay guys, I've wrote a simple upload method for my pictures

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    thumb_path = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            thumb_size = 128, 128
            thumb_path = "assests/uploads/thumb"+self.filename
            t = Image.open(self.path)
            t.thumbnail(thumb_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
            t.save(thumb_path, "JPEG")
        self.thumb_path = thumb_path
        super(Picture, self).save()

    def delete(self):
        os.unlink(self.thumb_path)
        os.unlink(self.path)
        super(Picture, self).delete()
```

As you can see this isn't the best method, i want to move on to the ImageField() to do most of my work, but i still want the flexiability to create a thumbnail and random filename.

would i need to create another model for PictureThumbnail? I don't really want to use any 3rd part extensions.

how could i use ImageField to make this work? All the iamges are gong to be uploaded to /assests/uploads/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an adapted version of:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1100/

Or depending on what exactly you need to do you can consider a template filter based approach something like this:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1887/

Comment: I'm using the first link. Howver ImageField() doesnt actually upload anything? It adds data to the db but no files are uploaded? Any ideas?

Comment: does the image field upload properly without the rest of the code? NOTE: the upload_to parameter is a local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting, and the user your python instance is running as must have write access to this.